# Cannot Get updated data from View in ASP MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to `ASP MVC`. I have created a visual 2013 MVC project using `RAZOR` view engine.
and here is my repartition:
My model class called EmployeeModel:

```
namespace MvcApplication3.Models
{
    public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int EmpId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeDep { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller Class :

```
using MvcApplication3.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication3.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        static List<EmployeeModel> _lstEmployee = new List<EmployeeModel>();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            _lstEmployee = GetEmployees();

            return View(_lstEmployee);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(int id, string empName, string empDep)
        {
            _lstEmployee = GetEmployees();
            _lstEmployee[id - 1].EmployeeName = empName;
            _lstEmployee[id - 1].EmployeeDep = empDep;
            return View(_lstEmployee);
        }

        private static List<EmployeeModel> GetEmployees()
        {
            var pvtList = new List<EmployeeModel>();
            var mod1 = new EmployeeModel { EmpId = 1, EmployeeName = "Employee1", EmployeeDep = "Dep1" };
            var mod2 = new EmployeeModel { EmpId = 2, EmployeeName = "Employee2", EmployeeDep = "Dep2" };
            var mod3 = new EmployeeModel { EmpId = 3, EmployeeName = "Employee3", EmployeeDep = "Dep3" };
            var mod4 = new EmployeeModel { EmpId = 4, EmployeeName = "Employee4", EmployeeDep = "Dep4" };
            pvtList.Add(mod1);
            pvtList.Add(mod2);
            pvtList.Add(mod3);
            pvtList.Add(mod4);
            return pvtList;
        }
    }
}
```

Then comes my Html Class called **Index.cshtml**

:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication3.Models.EmployeeModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<style type="text/css">
    .visible {
        display: inline;
    }
    .hide {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/HandWritten_scripts/IndexScript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="divResult">
    <h2>Simple MVC Grid with Row Level Edit & Save</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Employee ID</th>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>Employee Department</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var m in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @m.EmpId
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="divEmpName-@m.EmpId.ToString()" class="visible">@m.EmployeeName</div>
                    <input id="txtEmpName-@m.EmpId.ToString()" type="text" class="hide" value=@m.EmployeeName />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="divEmpDep-@m.EmpId.ToString()" class="visible">@m.EmployeeDep</div>
                    <input id="txtEmpDep-@m.EmpId.ToString()" type="text" class="hide" value=@m.EmployeeDep />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button id="btnEdit-@m.EmpId.ToString()" class="visible" onclick="ShowEdit(@m.EmpId); return false;">Edit</button>
                    <button id="btnSave-@m.EmpId.ToString()" class="hide" onclick="SaveEdit(@m.EmpId); return false;">Save</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

And finally my Javascript file called **IndexScript.Js**:

```
var ShowEdit = function (par) {
    $("#divEmpName-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
    $("#txtEmpName-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
    $("#divEmpDep-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
    $("#txtEmpDep-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
    $("#btnEdit-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
    $("#btnSave-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
};
function SaveEdit(par) {
    $("#divEmpName-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
    $("#txtEmpName-" + par).attr("class", "hide");
    $("#divEmpDep-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
    $("#txtEmpDep-" + par).attr("class", "hide");   
    $("#btnEdit-" + par).attr("class", "visible");
    $("#btnSave-" + par).attr("class", "hide");

    var empName = $("#txtEmpName-" + par).val();
    var empDep = $("#txtEmpDep-" + par).val();

    var url = '@Url.Action("Index","Home")';
    $.post(
        url,
        { Id: par, empName: empName, empDep: empDep },
        function (data) {
            $("#divResult").html(data);
        }
    );
```

So, here, my goal was divided in steps :

1- Display the list of enployees in a table **--> OK**

2- When i press edit button it displays data in text boxes the way i can edit **--> OK**

3- When i press Save button i save the data recently entred in the collection  **--> NOT OK !!!**

4- When i press Save button again , the data entred in the text box will be show in the div **---> NOT OK !!!**

I want this through modifying the collection of data (my model in this case). I tried doing this via `Url.Action` and `$post method` but that part is some code found in the internet , am not sure about it...

Can anyone tell me what is the beest practice in this case to reach my goal?

If i still should use `url.action` and $.post can any one explain me more about these two cynergy ?

ps: when i try to debug the override for the Index Action is never reached also

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int id, string empName, string empDep)
{
 _lstEmployee[id - 1].EmployeeName = empName;
 _lstEmployee[id - 1].EmployeeDep = empDep;
 return View(_lstEmployee);
}
```

I would be very thankful for any help, thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't appear to have included the jquery.js file in your view - what error message are you getting in the console?

Comment: i edited the post it is included, and i am getting no errors in the console ... just the data i modify in the text box does not appear int div after pressing save button ...

Comment: you should use Url.Content to avoid path issue : `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/HandWritten_scripts/IndexScript.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`. When you use dev tools like firebug  do you see a call to SaveEdit() method ?

Comment: @KarouiHaythem Does it have to be an ajax-post or could it also be a form-post?

Comment: @Wolle i am new to asp so can you please explain more?

Comment: @KarouiHaythem I posted an answer which would fit to your current ajax-post method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not set break point in java-script from Visual studio.
You have to write debugger; in javascript code.
One another thing in your post method of index. you must have to initialize employees list by
_lstEmployee = GetEmployees();

Comment: `[...] you can not set break point in java-script from Visual studio.`...  Sir, this is totally wrong.

Comment: And why did you know he didn't initialized his `_lstEmployee`? It is obvious that this is a private global property.

Comment: break point in javascript from visual studio will only work with IE. It will not work with chrome or FF

Comment: With installed web essentials extension for example, you can do this in chrome and ff, too. And other cool features like instand CSS-refreshing etc. ...

Comment: OK what about to forget the brak point in javascript... i removed that point ... can you focus on the [httpPost] index method or the $.post call in jquery plz ... i need more clarifications

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for the **best practices** sending form data to an action via JavaScript using jQuery. Here my advice:

Extend your view (.cshtml) like this: (Just wrap your input elements - in this case your table - in a form)

```
<h2>Simple MVC Grid with Row Level Edit & Save</h2>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Employee ID</th>
    <th>Employee Name</th>
    <th>Employee Department</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var m in Model)
    {
    @using(Html.BeginForm(/*set unique id*/))
    {
      <tr>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => m.EmpId)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => m.EmployeeName)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => m.EmployeeDep)</td>
        <td><!--buttons etc--></td>
      </tr>
    }
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can post this serialized form-data easily via jQuery-AJAX-functions to your action like this:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Home", "Remove")', $('#/*uniqueformid*/').serialize())
```

And now the best part: Your MVC-Action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Remove(EmployeeModel model)
{
  _lstEmployee.Remove(model); //This will work if your IEnumerable<EmployeeModel> is an List<EmployeeModel>
  return base.RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: How does the program know which employee to remove exactely? in $.post you just call remove action of homeController wich takes in parameters the model to remove... but in $.post method there ain't any parameter or variable tellin which model or employee to remove.. I don't really get it... :(

Comment: Edited my answer. If you do Html.EditorFor for each of your properties, ASP.NET MVC can easily map these properties to your object and build it for you. This is even possible with very complex/nested models. It's a kind of Microsoft voodoo magic ..